# iOS with XMPP Client

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework

I want to transfer image and video. I am able to transfer text but unable to transfer files.

**Here is the code to transfer file -**

```
NSString *messageStr = self.textView.text;

UIImage *imagePic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"];

if ([messageStr length] > 0 || [imagePic isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
    NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName: @"body"];
    [body setStringValue:messageStr];
    NSMutableDictionary *m = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:self.rosterJid];
    [message addChild:body];

    if ([imagePic isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
        [m setObject:imagePic forKey:@"image"];
        NSData *dataPic = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imagePic);
        NSXMLElement *photo = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"PHOTO"];
        NSXMLElement *binval = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"BINVAL"];
        [photo addChild:binval];
        NSString *base64String = [dataPic base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
        [binval setStringValue:base64String];
        [message addChild:photo];
    }
    [[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] sendElement: message];
    self.textView.text = @"";

}
```

How to receive files?
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you get message in `didRecieveMessage`?

Answer (score 0):

we tried messing with that system, I think that the string being passed was getting clipped. Something about the size string the server would accept. We eventually just decided to create a custom element with the type of message. Then uploaded media to an s3 bucket returning an reference id. created reference links that our client could handle based on type of message. so the only thing you transfer in the chat was an id to retrieve s3 image or video or whatever. It is a lot less constricting.